# Does ANTLR have built-in rules for unicode identifier-start and identifier-continue character sets?

Tags: antlr

I'm trying to write ANTLR 4 token rules for unicode-compatible identifiers. It appears to me that there's a notion of identifier-start and identifier-continue characters available in java.lang.Character; are there built-in ANTLR 4 character classes that correspond to these notions? I've grepped the source for 'isUnicodeIdentifierStart' without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ANTLR 4 set literals do not support character classes like regular expressions.

Comment: Hmm... I think I'm asking a slightly different question, but you may have answered it nonetheless. I'm not looking for regular expressions per se, but simply for a built-in constant like, say, UNICODE_IDENT_START. My current grammar has an ANTLR specification for both ident-start and ident-continue character sets, and they're 500 and 800 lines long, respectively.  It seems to me like this must be a common requirement for anyone building a unicode-based parser in ANTLR. Maybe this should take the form of a pull request?

Comment: ANTLR 4 aims to be more target-language-independent than previous versions, so binding an escape to a particular Java constant wouldn't make sense at the grammar level. The more general Unicode character classes you see in Regex engines would make sense though.

Comment: Yes, it appears that besides its Java-specific character classes, Java also includes a notion (isUnicodeIdentifierStart) that corresponds to Unicode Standard Annex #31, though I can't find any Java documentation that specifically refers to a Unicode document.